# Creating a counter with cookies

Tags: go

I have used the below code to create a counter using cookies. But I guess there is an issue with this `http.HandleFunc("/", foo)` function. Ideally the counter should be incremented only when the request is `http:localhost:8080` or `http:localhost:8080/`.

But the `count` is getting incremented even if I type some random text after `"/"` (ex: `http:localhost:8080/abcd`).

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", foo)
    http.Handle("/favicon.ico", http.NotFoundHandler())
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func foo(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    cookie, err := req.Cookie("my-cookie-counter")

    if err == http.ErrNoCookie {
        cookie = &http.Cookie{
            Name:  "my-cookie-counter",
            Value: "0",
        }
    }
    count, err := strconv.Atoi(cookie.Value)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    count++
    cookie.Value = strconv.Itoa(count)
    http.SetCookie(res, cookie)
    io.WriteString(res, cookie.Value)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [documented behavior](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux) of the `/` path when handled by the standard library's `ServeMux`, as you are doing.

Your options are:

1. Use a different router, which does exact matching.
2. In your handler, check for the expected path.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> http.HandleFunc("/", foo)
> ```

This works as a prefix matcher. It will match root and everything below. One way to make it match only the root is check `r.URL.Path` in your handler and not do work if the path is not the root.